# How does a binary executable know its location in memory?

Tags: assembly, binaryfiles

When loading a binary executable into memory, it can be disassembled or even looked at with a hex editor, and symbols from the assembly code. These always begin with something like 0x804... which I assume is the program memory section. But my question is, since these addresses aren't, say, offsets from the start of the program, how does the binary know where it will be loaded into memory?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're asking. Are you asking how a running executable determines its own location in memory? If so, why would it need to know? Also, is there some specific platform you're thinking about? See this document's section about [loaders](http://www.iecc.com/linker/linker08.html).

Comment: I'm more asking how the addresses in the program can be accurate. A program isn't always going to be able to be loaded into the same location, so how are the addresses pointing to the right thing.

Comment: Yes it can. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging

Comment: But if I create a program, copy it, and run both at the same time, doesn't that create issues?

Comment: You're confusing two things. One is separate address spaces. Another is relocation fixups.

Comment: @Jumhyn: Not on any modern operating system that gives every executable its own address space.

Comment: Any DLL has a preferred load address. If that address is already taken by another DLL, this DLL must be relocated to a free area of memory. Relocation means that all hard-coded address references in the DLL must be updated to reflect the new load address. Relocation fixups is a table of the locations where such updates are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Executable files usually have a header where one of the fields is the load address.

Comment: But a file cant *always* be loaded into the same location, can it?

Comment: On Windows, the default load location for an EXE is 0x400000 and that is always available to the EXE, which is always the first thing to load in a process, except for pre-loaded system DLLs that have (other) fixed locations.

Comment: @Jumhyn What could present an executable from being loaded at the same location? You're right for libraries -- the location could be in use for something else. But for executables, you're creating a new address space for the new executable, so it all starts free.